# Indy UPDServer in windows service not listening

Tags: sockets, delphi, udp, indy

I made a windows service wich is going to run in a server machine, and must listen client's requests to send files to them by UDP. I made the client application, and now I am trying to send UDP messages to the server, but the `UDPRead` procedure seems to not being called. I am working with Delphi XE7 in windows 10. The testing environment is:

- Client: Form application, with `TIdUDPServer` listening at port 27905.
  Sends and receives data correctly.
- Server: Windows service, with `TIdUDPServer` listening at port 27906.
  Sends data correctly with `TIdUDPServer.Send`, but it doesn't receive
  anything.
- Firewall and antivirus deactivated, just in case.
- Packages are being sent to the IP 127.0.0.1

I verified that the problem is the windows service because I harcoded a `TIdUDPServer.Send` in the Create method of the windows service's main class just to see if the client app receives it, and it does. Besides, I have sent UDP packages from the client to another form application that I recently developed to see if it is receiving data, and it does.

I am creating the `TIdUDPServer` object in the windows service app like this:

```
UDP := TIdUDPServer.Create(nil);
UDP.OnUDPRead := UDPRead;
UDP.DefaultPort := pListenPort;
UDP.Bindings.Clear;
UDP.Bindings.Add.IPVersion:=Id_IPv4;
UDP.Active := True;
```

And the procedure declaration is:

```
procedure TRed.UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TidBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
```

Probably I am missing something, but I can't find why is the UDPServer failing in the windows service. Any clue will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the command-line netstat or similar tool to verify the server is actually in a listening state, and see which IP/Port it is actually listening on (should be `0.0.0.0:27906`). Make sure the client is sending data to the correct IP/Port (`127.0.0.1:27906`). Try setting `TIdUDPServer.ThreadedEvent` to true. When `ThreadedEvent` is false, the `OnUDPRead` event is triggered by a call to `TThread.Synchronize()`. Your service is likely not processing `Synchronize()` requests. Setting `ThreadedEvent` to true bypasses that, just make sure your event handler uses thread-safe code inside of it.

Comment: Setting `TIdUDPServer.ThreadedEvent` to true fixed the problem, it is receiving data now, thank you very much! If you want, post the comment as an anwer so I can accept it.

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIdUDPServer` uses a worker thread to read incoming data in a loop, firing the `OnUDPRead` event whenever new data arrives.

By default, the `OnUDPRead` event handler is triggered by a call to `TThread.Synchronize()`, which means it fires in the context of the main UI thread (or at least any thread that calls the RTL's `CheckSynchronize()` function), not in the UDP worker thread.  Chances are that your service is not processing `Synchronize()` requests, which would explain why the event handler never fires.

So, you have two possible options:

1. Have your service call `CheckSynchronize()` periodically, such as in its `OnExecute` event.  Then the `OnUDPRead` event will fire in the context of the service thread.
2. set the `TIdUDPServer.ThreadedEvent` property to true (it is false by default).  When `ThreadedEvent` is true, the UDP worker thread bypasses `Synchronize()` and fires the `OnUDPRead` event directly.  As such, you would just have to make sure that your event handler contains thread-safe code inside of it.